# Getting Warning with Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, cell, fast-enumeration

I'm triying to access each item on an NSArray trough enumerateObjectsUsingBlock, since it let me use fast enumration and evaluating the index.

When I use findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock,

> I get Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main
>   thread. Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.

As I thought was used in the background to not block the Mainthread. Here is my code and what I'm triying to achieve its that I have two UIImageView container that I'm pulling the images from the result of the relation on that query. Since there are only container I tought it was better just to evaluate the index of NSArray.

Not sure how I can remedy that warning.

Thanks

```
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (objects != 0) {
            [objects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PFUser *object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                if (idx == 0) {
                    PFFile *userProfile = [object objectForKey:@"userPic"];
                    cell.promoter1.file = userProfile;
                    cell.promoter1.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                    [cell.promoter1 loadInBackground];                                                                                    
                    cell.promoter1Name.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                    cell.promoter1Name.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
                }
                if (idx == 1) {
                    PFFile *userProfile = [object objectForKey:@"userPic"];

                    cell.promoter2.file = userProfile;
                    cell.promoter2.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                    [cell.promoter2 loadInBackground];
                    NSAttributedString *promoter1Name;                                                                                  
                    cell.promoter2Name.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                    *stop = YES;
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troubleshooting my code, I realized that `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` does not cause this warning.

On another part of my code I had this:

```
PFUser *user = [PFQuery getUserObjectWithId:@"ebwFrl8PcF"];    
[relation addObject:user];
[self.event saveInBackground];
```

Which block the main thread.

I apologize.